# How to distinguish SRTM from DTED using C#?

Tags: c#, srtm, dted

Does anyone know how to easily distinguish between SRTM vs DTED programmatically without opening file metadata header? both are .dt1 or .dt2 extensions.

Answer (score 1):

SRTM is a data product, while DTED is a data product *and* a transfer format (MIL-PRF-89020B).  SRTM data in DTED format can't be easily distinguished from DTED (it wouldn't be of much use to DTED readers if it were).